# bsub - detach job but keep it alive in backround

Tags: docker, lsf

I have a bsub LSF job that runs a docker container, and i want to make the job runs in background (its important for me to keep the job AND the docker running, but in background).

Right now i am working with an interactive bsub job, i.e:

```
bsub -Is <docker creation script -d>
```

(Where "-d" makes the docker detach from job).

I have tried several combinations but got:

- If i am using the "-Is" flags, with docker -d, it exit immediately (The container stays but the job doesn't)
- If i am using "Is" without docker -d, it opens a terminal inside my current shell, which i want to avoid.
- if not using "ls" flags, the job exits immediately (while the docker keeps running and doesn't killed).

I will very appreciate a help with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the LSF docker feature? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_welcome/lsf_kc_docker.html

Comment: I do use. But there is nothing specific in this feature to make the job detached.